# Shortening deep imports / long namespaces

Tags: python, python-import

I am dealing with a package with long namespaces, and I was wondering if there is any way to shorten it.
For example, some imports look like

```
from LongNamespace.EvenLongerNamespace.AnotherOne.Class1 import Class1
from LongNamespace.EvenLongerNamespace.AnotherOne.Class2 import Class2
etc.
```

What I hoped would work is something like

```
Short = LongNamespace.EvenLongerNamespace.AnotherOne
from Short.Class1 import Class1
from Short.Class2 import Class2
etc.
```

but unfortunately that doesn't work.
I know that you can do

```
t = import LongNamespace.EvenLongerNamespace.AnotherOne
t.Class1
```

But that's not clean, I'd rather keep the `from x import y` structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class1` and `Class2` are attributes of the module `AnotherOne`, so you can assign them to variables like this:

```
from LongNamespace.EvenLongerNamespace import AnotherOne
Class1 = AnotherOne.Class1
Class2 = AnotherOne.Class2
```

You can also import several names in one statement:

```
from LongNamespace.EvenLongerNamespace.AnotherOne import Class1, Class2
```